# SSH Tunnel Blocked?

Tags: ssh, tunnel

Hi I have an SSH tunnel setup from my work to home.  I use it to tunnel IMs and some web browsing.  It was working fine until today for some reason.  I can still ssh into my home box and can access websites from it so I'm not sure what is the problem.  I used putty to set up the tunnel and setup pidgin and google chrome to use a socks proxy.  I'm using port 443 for my ssh.

Comment: If you can establish an ssh connection at all, you're probably fine. Maybe your forwarded local port is in use. Try another local port to tunnel and report back please.

Comment: Most companies severely frown on this sort of behavior and in every company I have ever worked for this was a violation of company policy at the least and a terminable offense at worst as a violation of company security policy.  It is highly likely your employer detected your connection and shut it down.

Comment: @BBlake - Good thing I don't work for such a douchey company. I don't blame them necessarily, but "You can't stop the signal Mal". Bet they're having all sorts of new fun with Smartphones - cause that's where I'd be going.. Probably just chain some ssh tunnels through my smartphone's connection (at work).

Comment: @BBlake - I'm sure glad you don't work here.  Besides being the right thing to do for their customer's data, many companies implement policies because of external requirements to do so.  In other words, their business contracts may require the controls.  Having folks work around controls put in place in part to keep customers that pays their paycheck may be short-sighted and selfish.

Comment: It's pretty much standard policy throughout the industries I've worked in (government, health care, insurance, financial).  And I can understand why dealing with the information that we do.